# Nokia here maps search manager

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to make a reverse geocoding call to nokia here maps api:

```
var searchManager = new nokia.maps.search.Manager();
var searchCallback = function (observedManager, key, value) {
               if (value == "finished" && observedManager.locations[0]) {
              alert(observedManager.locations[0].displayPosition);
           } else {
                alert("Geocoding failed.");
           }
         };
searchManager.addObserver("state", searchCallback);

function ricerca(){
var text = $('#search').val();
alert(text);
searchManager.search(text);
}
```

When I make the call, I get the following error:

"uncaught type error: cannot call method "search" of undefined"

I'm not so experienced in javascript, maybe it's a stupid issue, but I got stuck here for a lot of time...does anyone understand where my error is?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem you are experiencing is that the variable `searchManager` you are setting up isn't in scope within the function `ricerca()` - admittedly this shouldn't be the case from the code snippet you have pasted, but maybe if you are defining the `searchManager` in a separate function it isn't being set with global scope?

i.e. if you have:

```
function setup(){
  var searchManager = new nokia.maps.search.Manager();
  // etc...
}

function ricerca(){
 searchManager.search(text);
}
```

Try altering it to:

```
var searchManager;
function setup(){
  searchManager = new nokia.maps.search.Manager();
  // etc...
}

function ricerca(){
 searchManager.search(text);
}
```

Second possibility would be to check that you are using the **latest** 2.5.3 version of the API, with the additional `with` parameter if necessary.

**Maps API for JavaScript**

If you are using the **public** JavaScript API, you should load the library with the following `<script>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://js.api.here.com/se/2.5.3/jsl.js?with=all"></script>
```

and search using the **static** `nokia.places.search.manager` as shown in this [example](http://developer.here.com/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-js/places-search/search-by-address.html)

**Enterprise Maps API for JavaScript**

If however you are using the **Enterprise** JavaScript API, the `<script>` tag is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.api.here.com/ee/2.5.3/jsl.js?with=all"></script>
```

and the syntax is also different and uses an **instance** of the `nokia.maps.search.Manager` as shown in this example [here](https://developer.here.com/enterprise/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-js/places-search/map-search.html). Check that your `app_code` and `app_id` are correctly registered to use this API.

Your code snippet appears to be a mixture of the two, and may be from an older version of the APIs.